# Identifying DDOS Attacks on Windows 2008 Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, ddos, denial-of-service

I recently was notified by my monitoring service that a few Windows 2008 servers (hyper-v instances) were down.

I logged into the Hyper-V box and noticed everything was super slow. I opened task manager and saw that while CPU and RAM were fine, network utilization on our "Public" NIC was at 99%.

This lasted for about 10 minutes, during which time I found that disabling inbound connections for one of the servers caused the network saturation to drop to normal levels. I disabled that server's inbound connections to allow the other servers to operate, and eventually the traffic went away.

I suspect this was a DDOS or regular Denial of Service attack, but it seems pretty random. The server in question is very low visibility and not a lot of value would come from someone taking it down.

What would be the best way to tell if I am experiencing a DDOS attack? Is there anything else that you could think of that would cause this, and, if so, what should I look for?

EDIT: This happened again. I tried netstat -noa but didn't see anything useful. I was hoping there was some command or program I could run that would show me how much bandwidth each IP is using (i.e., it says network utilization is 100%, but how does that add up). Does anything like that exist?

Comment: What is the role of the offending server?

Comment: The server that was getting hit was a web application server.

Comment: Is there anything in the system or application logs?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the event logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following in *[Windows Server 2008 TCP/IP Protocols and Services](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780735624474/ch11lev1sec3)*.

> To see a SYN attack in progress on a
>   computer running Windows Server 2008
>   or Windows Vista, use the Netstat.exe
>   tool at a command prompt to display
>   the active TCP connections. For
>   example:
>
> [image]
>
> This is an example of a SYN attack.
>   There are a number of TCP connections
>   in the SYN_ RECEIVED state, and the
>   foreign address is a spoofed private
>   address with incrementally increasing
>   TCP port numbers. The SYN_RECEIVED is
>   the state of a TCP connection that has
>   received a SYN, sent a SYN-ACK, and is
>   waiting for the final ACK.

which is confusing, because later on it says:

> TCP in Windows Server 2008 and Windows
>   Vista use SYN attack protection to
>   prevent a SYN attack from overwhelming
>   the computer.

...so if that is the case, how would the above command help?

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help?

[Detecting DoS / DDoS Attack on a Windows 2003 / 2008 Server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/detect-ddos-dos-attack-on-windows-server/)

> netstat is a command line utility which displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections in a system. Type the following command to see all connections:
>
> ```
> netstat -noa
> ```
>
> Where,
>
> 1. n: Displays active TCP connections, however, addresses and port numbers are expressed numerically and no attempt is made to determine names.
> 2. o: Displays active TCP connections and includes the process ID (PID) for each connection. You can find the application based on the PID on the Processes tab in Windows Task Manager.
> 3. a: Displays all active TCP connections and the TCP and UDP ports on which the computer is listening.

Comment: This would help if you have an active attack condition. Not later. It would have really helped to predict such attacks and keep the inbound traffic mirrored into a 1TB rolling packet-capture for that matter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Servers are usually DoS'ed with connections rather than packets.
So, a full utilization of the network path is not always necessary.

If yours was a DDoS/DoS, it should have tripped your IDS in the inbound path (assuming you have one).

Since you say it was a low visiblity web server, could it be someone inside or outside your enterprise mirroring it with a full rate `wget` kind of activity? That would choke your HyperV system if you have sufficient bandwidth on you uplink. It would also explain a short lived 'attack'.

Comment: Well that's the strange thing...the IIS logs aren't any larger than normal...so I don't think it was a bunch of http connections. This particular system is login protected (asp.net security), so wget wouldn't be easy to do. We have a 10 mbit inbound connection dedicated to this server (from our ISP, it is a hosted server). There isn't an IDS in place.

Comment: Can you confirm that the high network activity was definitely from outside your network (that is, from the uplink) and there are no failed-communications logs in your Windows server? Things like Conficker are known to attempt a large-scale exploit attempt. Yet, based on what you have said, I doubt Conficker itself is involved here.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely from outside, and inbound. If I disabled inbound traffic (but not outbound) to that IP, things went back to normal. What do you mean by "failed-communication logs"? Where would those be?

Comment: @Adam, I was referring to things like EventLog messages that indicate a login attemt was made with well known ID strings (like admin, root, etc) registered on your windows server `%SystemRoot%\system32\eventvwr.msc /s` security logs.

Comment: Did you try to capture any part of this traffic to see its nature? I ask because you were around when the problem occurred. A capture helps a lot in identifying what was really happening (see my other exaggerated comment about the 1TB rolling capture).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...how would you recommend capturing the traffic within a Hyper-V environment? Would Wireshark work do you think?

Comment: I have used wireshark (tshark) on VMWare machines. But, not on Hyper-V. Guess it should.